# Want to sort large csv file having date in the format ddMONYYYY using unix sort command

Tags: unix, sorting, csv

```
aman@gmail.com,"08OCT2012"
abc@gmail.com,"11JUL2012"
def@gmail.com,"16DEC2010"
abc@gmail.com,"16MAR2011"
aman@gmail.com,"21APR2011"
abc@apple.com,"12DEC2010"
xyz@fb.com,"06MAR2011"
```

Want to sort above csv using unix sort command 1st by email address and then by date

I have tried something like

```
sort -k1 -k212 -k23M -k26 file.csv
```

But it didn't work out. Anybody has any idea how to sort this csv?

Answer (score 2):

You may need `sort -t,` to indicate the delimiter is a comma `,`.

Then, something like this should work:

```
sort -t, -k1 -k2 file.csv
```

Anyway, to sort by date you should firstly do some -> to UNIX stamp conversion in your date field.

Comment: what if i want to sort lines by 3rd column from last no of columns can vary from column to column?But only 3rd column from last remains same

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Always use ISO8601 in tabular data because it is the only true format which can be lexically sorted (big endian).